# How to read a pixel color in python (not from an Image)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get a value of RGB from a pixel in python using pygame

not getting the RGB from pixels in an image

Comment: Can you add some code showing what you have already tried?

Comment: Can the question be more specific as to what are expecting and what you have.

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.Surface.get_at((coordinateX, coordinateY))`